# Re wiring events on winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If I have inside MyPanel.Designer.cs 
events for certain buttons like

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{         
      this.btnPageRefresh.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(74, 18);
      this.btnPageRefresh.Name = "btnPageRefresh";               
      this.btnPageRefresh.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.PageRefreshClick);
}
```

This is button used on custom power point add in, I have a problem when addIn is loaded second time in new window my buttons (in this case btnPageRefresh) doesn't work.

I've found point inside application where I should put rewiring event for this click

```
private void Application_AfterNewPresentation(PowerPoint.Presentation Pres)
        {
           ... 
           this.mainForm.RebindEvents();
        }
```

here I have available `public event EventHandler PageRefresh;` 
I have also available

```
private void PageRefreshClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
```

having all this information how can I rebind this events, cause buttons doesn't respond when addIn is loaded second time.

update:
inside MyApp.css which is some kind of mvvm pattern here, I'm wiring button events on the form which is received as param in the constructor

```
public class MyApp
 {
    private readonly Application app;
    private readonly IMainView mainForm;

    public MyApp(IMainView mainForm)
    {
       this.app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;           
       this.mainForm = mainForm;
       this.mainForm.PageRefresh += this.OnPageRefresh;
    }

    private void OnPageRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ...
    }   
}
```

and MyApp is called from addIn startup

```
 public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;
        private SidePanel mainForm;
        private MyApp myApp;        

           private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {

                this.mainForm = new MySidePanel();
                this.myApp = new AppManager(this.mainForm as IMainView);

                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AfterNewPresentation += this.Application_AfterNewPresentation;
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AfterPresentationOpen += this.Application_AfterPresentationOpen;
            }
    }
```

Comment: you should show the full code block for the btnPageRefresh including method signature.

Comment: Please post a full code. It's unclear how your control is created or what is main form and how are they initialized.

Comment: Question is updated, @RezaAghaei